# Prestashop get the product default image from the product name?

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

In Prestashop I want to know by which pattern prestashop shows the product default image? I mean lets say I have a mysql query for prestashop like this

```
SELECT ps_product.id_product,ps_product.id_category_default,description_short,ps_product_lang.name FROM ps_product_lang,ps_product WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang=1 AND ps_product.id_product=ps_product_lang.id_product
```

Now here I will get the product id, product category, description, and name.
Now according to prestashop default products and database I have for the product iPod Nano the database fields are like

```
id_product  id_category_default
  1               3
```

Now if I want to get the product image I will use

```
img/p/id_product/id_category_default/id_product.id_category_default
```

This will make the img src like

```
img/p/1/3/13.jpg
```

Now when I used that I got the image for Belkin Leather Folio for iPod

but with the same condition I got the exact image for ipod shuffle. So can someone kindly tell me how to get the exact default image for the product name? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this query to get the image id of the cover image (image displayed in category view) for a product:

```
SELECT id_image FROM ps_image WHERE cover = 1 AND id_product = $idProduct
```

Then you can generate the image path with the following code:

```
$imgPath = 'img/p/';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($idImage); $i++) {
  $imgPath .= $idImage[$i] . '/';
}
$imgPath .= $idImage . '.jpg';
```

If you want to get the image id of the default thumbnail displayed in the product view then you can use this query:

```
SELECT id_image FROM ps_image WHERE position = 1 AND id_product = $idProduct
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But can you tell me what will be the exact path for the image. As because img tag shows image from src. so to show an image we need our image path like this
`<img src="img/p/1/5/15.jpg" alt="" />` for the product id 1. Now according to your answer I am getting the image name 15.jpg and thats good but how to get the image path? Without image path how can I use that image name?
According to your answer image path will `<img src="img/p/15.jpg">` So now can you tell me how to get 1 and 5 as because the right image path for the product_id 1 is `<img src="img/p/1/5/15.jpg">`

Comment: The image path is generated from the digits of the image id. For 6 it will be img/p/6/6.jpg. For 16 it will be img/p/1/6/16.jpg, for 123 it will be /img/p/1/2/3/123.jpg. Check the PHP code in my answer.

Comment: in your answer you have used 
`for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($idImage); $i++) {
  $imgPath .= $idImage[$i] . '/';
}`
So can you tell me how to get the variable $idImage?

Comment: $idImage is the result of this query: `SELECT id_image FROM ps_image WHERE cover = 1 AND id_product = $idProduct`

Comment: ok..I got that but as you can see I have already query above I have written 
`SELECT ps_product.id_product,ps_product.id_category_default,description_short,ps_product_lang.name FROM ps_product_lang,ps_product WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang=1 AND ps_product.id_product=ps_product_lang.id_product`
 I have used this one for getting product id,name, desc. So can u tell me how to merge your query with this so that I will get product id, product name, desc, category id, image id at a same time?

Comment: `SELECT ps_product.id_product,ps_product.id_category_default,description_short,name,id_image FROM ps_product_lang,ps_product,ps_image WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang=1 AND ps_product.id_product=ps_product_lang.id_product AND ps_product.id_product=ps_image.id_product AND cover=1`

Comment: Nope that one showing 
`#1054 - Unknown column 'id_i‌​mage' in 'field list'`

Comment: Works for me, but try this then: `SELECT p.id_product, p.id_category_default, l.description_short, l.name, i.id_image FROM ps_product AS p LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang AS l ON p.id_product = l.id_product LEFT JOIN ps_image AS i ON p.id_product = i.id_product WHERE l.id_lang = 1 AND i.cover = 1`